# Depth First Search starting at bottom of tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to find the furthest node from a specific node in a Binary Search Tree. For this I want to implement Depth First Search of the tree. However, I don't know how I can do it starting at a bottom node. I have `preOrder()`, `inOrder()` and `posOrder()` implemented but they only work for the root node. When I try to give it a node at the bottom, only that node is returned, because I can't seem to access its ancestors. How can I change my code to do this?

```
public Iterable<E> inOrder(){
    List<E> snapshot = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root!=null)
      inOrderSubtree(root, snapshot);   // fill the snapshot recursively
    return snapshot;    
}
private void inOrderSubtree(Node<E> node, List<E> snapshot) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    inOrderSubtree(node.getLeft(), snapshot);
    snapshot.add(node.getElement());
    inOrderSubtree(node.getRight(), snapshot);
}
```

Comment: How is the tree structured? How will you traverse from child to parent node?

Comment: You need a reference to the parent to get up in the tree. Than the most naive approach would be: create a new tree with the start-node as root and than search for the lowest leave. I recommend to try it with the old pen and paper approach to get an idea how to implement it.